# This code issue when loading page

Tags: asp.net, html, iis

I moved this page and the contents of my root from one server to another and when I try to load the following page I get the error below. Any ideas?

**Configuration Error**

***Description:*** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

***Parser Error Message:*** It is an error to use a section registered as `allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'` beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

***Source Error:***

> **Line 24:**             during development.
>
> **Line 25:**         `-->`
>
> **Line 26:**      `<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">`
>
> **Line 27:**          `<providers>`
>
> **Line 28:**              `<clear/>`
>
> **Source File:** E:\Domains\m\mockcourt.org.uk\user\htdocs\mcc\web.config    **Line:
> 26**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo

Comment: If one of the answer solve your issue, or help you to find the problem, can you please accept it and vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is not properly configured in IIS.

You need to set your site as an application in ISS.

Here are [instructions for IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b5488995-fa99-460f-96d7-29d1ddcf3fac.mspx?mfr=true). Even if you're using a different version, this will put you on the right track.

Comment: Your answer is too general, is like an answer saying "you have a problem that you need to configure it and fix it". Actually the site is parce the web.config, and gives an error, so its setup as asp.net application ! (so you are not correct on that) Proof : check the page http://mockcourt.org.uk/mcc gives the asp.net error, so its run as asp,net application.

Comment: @Aristos, I disagree completely. The error even indicates that the site is not configured as an application in IIS. I've been developing in .net for many years, and have gotten this error many times. This is **one** possible solution.

Comment: Yes it is configure it, in the upper directory. If you developing sites for many years you should direct recognize that this is a share environment and he has not control on iis, and the shared space that they give him have the asp.net ! so the issue here is the directory, have not place them in the correct directory !

Answer (score -1):

You have move your site in a directory **that is NOT the root of this asp.net application**.

Is still configured to run asp.net, but you have place all your files on a sub directory and not on root.

So two thinks you can do, place the files on the correct root directory, or if you need to run this together with the other application on the root create a new asp.net application on the directory that you have added.

from your log *probably* this is where you must put them : `E:\Domains\m\mockcourt.org.uk\user\htdocs\` and NOT this directory "E:\Domains\m\mockcourt.org.uk\user\htdocs\mcc\", check the rest directories to find the correct one.