# Issues with Web Config file and Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, web-config

When running my application in debug mode (Visual Studio 2012) I'm using this in my web config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectory">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add
            applicationName="TheManhattanProject" name="ActiveDirectory"
            type="TheManhattanProject.Security.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider"
            domain="mydomain" groupMode="" connectionString="LDAP:(insert correct string here)"
    />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

The application gets an error that highlights the "RoleManager" section at the top.  It literally crashes before the page loads.

This is for my MVC4 Web Application to authenticate (Windows; Not forms) against Active Directory and I haven't been able to find a fix just yet.

If I haven't been clear in what I'm asking, please ask me and I'll try to clear things up!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  The error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 31:     </httpHandlers>
Line 32: 
Line 33:     <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectory">
Line 34:       <providers>
Line 35:         <clear/>
```

Comment: Can you provide the error text or a screenshot?

Comment: Don't worry about the connectionString,  it's correct in the running application.

Comment: @AaronD: There you go.  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)