# Error during forms authentication implementatioin

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, connection, config

I am trying to implement the following code to test forms authentication in the web app.

```
<location path="Test.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Test.aspx">
        </forms>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Error:

> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.***

I already did clean in release mode then in debug mode then build solution. i also tried IIS express but still getting this error , anyone knows the solution , please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)

Comment: Side note: please avoid adding text like "searched a lot", "new here", "thank you notes" not directly related to problem described in your posts.

Comment: okey ! but i used these words because i know duplicates are present but the solution over there are not solving my problem !

Comment: I think it will be easier to help if you port all your web.config.

Comment: for a testing period i m using only one web.config.. still not working