# Data Service error

Tags: dataservice, devextreme

http://dynamicshell.com/dataservice/DataService.svc
I dont have any idea what should i do.
I only follow same steps in this video. then publish DataService to my hosting.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM5j4t6-3_4&index=2&list=PL8h4jt35t1wjGvgflbHEH_e3b23AA30-z

Please help me

Comment: You should clarify your question more, rather than giving links.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the application is correctly configured on IIS?

This could be the possible solution: [Error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)

Hope it can help.