# How do you solve "allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level" error message when adding a web app to another web app?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-7

Detailed error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

There seems to be loads of questions (and different answers) on this error, which have been useful for me to understand my specific position (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)), but none seem to be able to pick out exactly how I can fix it.

I've written a web application (lets call it WATop), which I've added as it's own website in IIS (right click on 'Sites' > 'Add Website...') . Within this I've added another web application (lets call this WAMulti) by right clicking my newly created site and clicking 'Add Application...'. The error, as far as I can tell, is therefore being thrown because specifically the authentication mode cannot be set beyond the application level, which is currently WATop, and is trying to be set again by WAMulti. Many suggestions are related to merging the web.config files, but unfortunately this isn't an option as WAMulti is used by more than just WATop. In the other places it's used it needs to define this as it's the only web app (and hence it works).

So far I've not come across a situation where this relates to a web app within a web app.

I'm using IIS 7 and have the WAMulti setup as a web application in WATop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end was to comment out anything within the  tag (not the tag itself) within the web.config of the nested web app. It looks like anything within these tags can only be defined at application level.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://dotnet-magic.blogspot.com/2008/11/it-is-error-to-use-section-registered.html), below it might be helpful

Solution :- There Are Mainly One of the Two Reason Why you Got this Error Message.

1. If you Have Not configured your asp.net application in IIS.  If you have not Configure your application to run on IIS First Configure your Site to Run on IIS.For that Create Virtual Directory From IIS and Give Permission to Application (Read,Write)
2. If Above is Not Problem Then There are Mainly Problem of Two or many Web.Config Exists on your Site.When you Open Some Site and if Software Crate Backup of that Application then Software mainly Do Create Subfolder and Copy All Files + Web.Config in Application.Just Remove this Subfolder web.config from Subfolder.

Also there is another [good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo) discussing this issue