# vb.net web form Error:It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In a vb.net 2010 web form application, I just installed a third party tool on my workstation and the install modified the web config file to add references to some new files that are being accessed. Now I am getting the following error message,

"Error 1 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS".

Thus can you give me detailed directions on what I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to configure the application in IIS.  There's much more information over here:  [Error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)