# ASP.NET MVC Publish fail - ASPCONFIG allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Publishing of a MVC project from VS 2013/2012 fails just after adding to the web.config

```
<authentication ... />
```

or

```
<caching>
```

etc (section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication').

**Patient:**

AspNetCompiler (aspnet_compiler.exe)

**Error:**

    `...\myProject\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\web.config(81,0): Error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
    The command exited with code 1.
    Done building project "myProject.csproj" -- FAILED.`

**Reason:**
(Visual Studio 2013, 2012)
The **bin** folder of the ASP.NET MVC site/project contains the same web.config as the root site folder!
(**This folder is created constantly by ASP.NET MVC project/publish**)

```
site_root\web.config
site_root\bin\web.config
```

**Question**

What to do with the **AspNetCompiler (aspnet_compiler.exe)** and this **bin\web.config**? It always there.
I want to publish from my VS ))

---

Solution [Delete Files="$(SolutionDir)\$(ProjectDir)\bin***.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo/26944167#26944167) was useless.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after updating a NuGet package. Look for a folder named "NuGetBackup" inside your site's "App_Data" folder. If you find it, delete it or move it outside of your website files.

The error is caused by having a copy of the root web.config in one of those backups.

Comment: I don't see such a folder. Thank you! I'll try something in this direction.