# Server Error due to configuration, and can't set up machine key as shown below

Tags: c#, asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

`Description:` An error occurred during the processing of a `configuration` file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

`Parser Error Message:` It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 9:    </connectionStrings>
Line 10:   <system.web>
Line 11:     <machineKey decryption="AES"           decryptionKey="D5BE1C3052D930D3D425E96D7A424FEDF67AC4CDDD1BB523A8F420A6C9AB8779"     validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="8AE05954FF94F7FE9972E9774B94B1E7F6
Line 12: 4717979FE0B230158BC7A8AE588994E7EC66CFAC555BA276AEC669BBE8B15DC52A04B06395018BFF3BBAE221E0149A" />
Line 13:     <customErrors mode="Off"/>

Source File: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\connectnewwings.com\httpdocs\admin\web.config    Line: 11 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

Comment: have you set virtual directory for application in IIS

Comment: I hosted it in web server.. I dont know to set virtual directory..

Comment: Post the IIS manager image in querstion.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration information for an ASP.NET website is defined in one or more Web.config files. The configuration settings are applied in a hierarchical manner. There's a “global” Web.config file that spells out the baseline configuration information for all websites on the web server; this file lives in the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\version\CONFIG folder. You can also have a Web.config file in the root folder of your website. This Web.config file can override settings defined in the “global” Web.config file, or add new ones. Additionally, you may have Web.config files in the subfolders of your website, which define new configuration settings or override configuration settings defined in Web.config files higher up in the hierarchy.

Certain configuration elements in Web.config cannot be defined beyond the application level, meaning that they must be defined in the “global” Web.config file or in the Web.config file in the website's root folder. The  element is one such example. The above error message indicates that there is a Web.config file in one of the website's subfolders than has one of these configuration elements that cannot be defined beyond the application level.

Source: http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx

Comment: And I found a similar question, please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)

Comment: I could't follow this.. i just added <machineKey decryption="AES"           decryptionKey="D5BE1C3052D930D3D425E96D7A424FEDF67AC4CDDD1BB523A8F420A6C9AB8779"     validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="8AE05954FF94F7FE9972E9774B94B1E7F6
Line 12: 4717979FE0B230158BC7A8AE588994E7EC66CFAC555BA276AEC669BBE8B15DC52A04B06395018BFF3BBAE221E0149A" />

Comment: Go to your IIS management console, find the directory called site under the Default Web Site (which is under the Sites node), right click on site and choose Convert to Application.

Comment: What version of IIS? Please try to remove the virtual directory in IIS. Then, re-create the virtual directory and configure it as an application

Comment: I dont know how to do it.