# errors in web.config in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, web-config

I have a application running in IIS 7. But now I want the application run to in visual studio 2013. So I open the application as a webapplication. But now I get errors in the web.config file. This is the webconfig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- application specific settings -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="application.add.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="Dynamicweb.Admin.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="bdMijnVerploegenModule.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="bdRegisterUserModule.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="bdNavisionLibrary.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="bdDynamicWebLibrary.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="bdPlaceOrderNotification.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataAccess_DynamicWebEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess_DynamicWeb.csdl|res://*/DataAccess_DynamicWeb.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess_DynamicWeb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-UON3ACI\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Dynamicweb-Verploegen-Test_new;user id='VERPLOEGEN\Niels';password='';multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-UON3ACI\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=yes;Initial catalog=Verploegen-Test;user id='VERPLOEGEN\Niels'" name="NAV2DWservice.Properties.Settings.NAVconnectionString" />   
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <!--  HttpCompressionSettings
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Folder / Files where http compression is disabled.
        '
        ' Paths are checked from left to right.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    <add key="HttpCompressionSettings" value="/Admin/Public,Admin/Access"/>
    <add key="HttpCompressionpreferredAlgorithm" value="deflate|gzip"/>
    <add key="HttpCompressionLevel" value="high|normal|low"/>
    -->
    <add key="HttpCompressionSettings" value="/Admin/Public,/Admin/Statisticsv2,/Admin/FileManager,/Admin/Module/Ecom/,/Admin/Module/Ipaper,/Admin/Module/News/News_Module_List.aspx,/WebResource.axd" />
    <add key="HttpCompressionForceSettings" value="/Admin/Public/eCom/InstantSearch.ashx" />
    <add key="HttpCompressionPreferredAlgorithm" value="deflate" />
    <add key="HttpCompressionLevel" value="low" />
    <add key="GeoLocationServiceToken" value="TJMqI2937C" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000" />

    <!--Verploegen appSettings-->
    <add key="DWWebApiServiceURL" value="http://acceptatie.verploegen.bluedesk.nl/webapi/" />
    <add key="DWWebApiServiceToken" value="2E0B7643-6B65-4812-8B8A-F72F960D369C" />
    <add key="HideCategories" value="99999,99999.99999,99999.99999.99999,99998" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <!--  DYNAMIC DEBUG COMPILATION
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging symbols (.pdb information)
          into the compiled page. Because this creates a larger file that executes
          more slowly, you should set this value to true only when debugging and to
          false at all other times. For more information, refer to the documentation about
          debugging ASP.NET files.

    -->
    <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="GS" type="Dynamicweb.Controls.Design.GlobalSettingsExpressionBuilder, Dynamicweb.Controls" />
      </expressionBuilders>
    </compilation>
    <!--  CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES
          Set customErrors mode="On" or "RemoteOnly" to enable custom error messages, "Off" to disable.
          Add <error> tags for each of the errors you want to handle.

          "On" Always display custom (friendly) messages.
          "Off" Always display detailed ASP.NET error information.
          "RemoteOnly" Display custom (friendly) messages only to users not running
           on the local Web server. This setting is recommended for security purposes, so
           that you do not display application detail information to remote clients.
    -->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <!--  AUTHENTICATION
          This section sets the authentication policies of the application. Possible modes are "Windows",
          "Forms", "Passport" and "None"

          "None" No authentication is performed.
          "Windows" IIS performs authentication (Basic, Digest, or Integrated Windows) according to
           its settings for the application. Anonymous access must be disabled in IIS.
          "Forms" You provide a custom form (Web page) for users to enter their credentials, and then
           you authenticate them in your application. A user credential token is stored in a cookie.
          "Passport" Authentication is performed via a centralized authentication service provided
           by Microsoft that offers a single logon and core profile services for member sites.
    -->
   <!--<authentication mode="Windows" />-->
    <!--  AUTHORIZATION
          This section sets the authorization policies of the application. You can allow or deny access
          to application resources by user or role. Wildcards: "*" mean everyone, "?" means anonymous
          (unauthenticated) users.
    -->
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <!-- Allow all users -->
      <!--  <allow     users="[comma separated list of users]"
                             roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
                  <deny      users="[comma separated list of users]"
                             roles="[comma separated list of roles]"/>
            -->
    </authorization>
    <!--  APPLICATION-LEVEL TRACE LOGGING
          Application-level tracing enables trace log output for every page within an application.
          Set trace enabled="true" to enable application trace logging.  If pageOutput="true", the
          trace information will be displayed at the bottom of each page.  Otherwise, you can view the
          application trace log by browsing the "trace.axd" page from your web application
          root.
    -->
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <!--  SESSION STATE SETTINGS
          By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session.
          If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL.
          To disable cookies, set sessionState cookieless="true".
    -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="512000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true" requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,>,*,%,:,\,?" maxUrlLength="2000" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
    <!--  GLOBALIZATION
          This section sets the globalization settings of the application.
    -->
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
    <httpModules>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="globalsettings.aspx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="globalsettings.xml.aspx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="ecom.xml.aspx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="updates.xml.aspx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Transitional" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2048000000" />
                <denyQueryStringSequences>
                    <add sequence="dbstat=true" />
                    <add sequence="debug=true" />
                </denyQueryStringSequences>
                <denyUrlSequences>
                </denyUrlSequences>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <add name="globalsettings.xml.aspx_*" path="globalsettings.xml.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="Globalsettings.aspx_*" path="globalsettings.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ecom.xml.aspx_*" path="ecom.xml.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="updates.xml.aspx_*" path="updates.xml.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="_sys_crm_report_xml.aspx_*" path="_sys_crm_report_xml.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="K*.K" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="K*.K" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <!--<add name="HttpCompression" type="HttpCompression.HttpCompressionModule,HttpCompression"/>-->
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests>
        <remove path="*" />
        <add path="*">
          <traceAreas>
            <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
          </traceAreas>
          <failureDefinitions statusCodes="500" />
        </add>
      </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Admin/Public/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIPLookupService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Endpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdIntelligenceService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BingPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="wsPakkeshopSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://geolocation.dynamicweb-cms.com/IPLookup/IPLookupService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IIPLookupService" contract="dk.dynamicweb.geolocation.IIPLookupService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IIPLookupService" />
      <endpoint address="https://epayment.bbs.no/Netaxept.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Endpoint" contract="no.bbs.epayment.INetaxept" name="Endpoint" />
      <endpoint address="https://epayment-test.bbs.no/Netaxept.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Endpoint" contract="no.bbs.epayment.test.INetaxept" name="Endpoint" />
      <endpoint address="https://adcenterapi.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/V8/CampaignManagement/AdIntelligenceService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAdIntelligenceService" contract="BingSuggestionAPIwebSrv.IAdIntelligenceService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdIntelligenceService" />
      <endpoint address="http://api.bing.net:80/soap.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BingPortBinding" contract="net.bing.api.BingPortType" name="BingPort" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.gls.dk/webservices_v2/wsPakkeshop.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsPakkeshopSoap" contract="GLSwsPakkeshop.wsPakkeshopSoap" name="wsPakkeshopSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <application.add.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="NavUserGroupID" serializeAs="String">
            <value>264</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="AlternativeProductsGroupName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Alternatieve Producten</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NavisionRootGroupID" serializeAs="String">
            <value>GROUP129</value>
        </setting>     
    </application.add.Properties.Settings>  
    <Dynamicweb.Admin.MySettings>
      <setting name="Dynamicweb_Admin_dk_dynamicsystems_webservice_IPLookup" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://webservice.dynamicsystems.dk/ip2location/lookup.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Dynamicweb_Admin_dk_dynamicweb_templates_TemplateTagsService" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://templates.dynamicweb.dk/Admin/Public/WebServices/TemplateTags/TemplateTags.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Dynamicweb_Admin_dk_dynamicweb_versions_VersionsInformation" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://license.dynamicweb-cms.com/VersionsInformation.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </Dynamicweb.Admin.MySettings>
    <bdMijnVerploegenModule.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="NAVDomain" serializeAs="String">
        <value>VERPLOEGEN</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVUserName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>bluedesk</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Verploegen01</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVAccountServiceURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Account</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVUserServiceURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/User</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVProductServiceURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Product</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVOrderServiceURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Order</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVInvoiceServiceURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Invoice</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrderStatusIdNavisionOrder" serializeAs="String">
        <value>OS11</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrderStatusIdNavisionError" serializeAs="String">
        <value>OS12</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="StockUpdateUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://acceptatie.verploegen.bluedesk.nl/webapi/StockUpdate?productidlist</value>
      </setting>
    </bdMijnVerploegenModule.Properties.Settings>
    <bdRegisterUserModule.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="EmailSubject" serializeAs="String">
              <value>Klant registratie</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="EmailFrom" serializeAs="String">
              <value>noreply@verploegen.nl</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="EmailFromName" serializeAs="String">
              <value>Verploegen B.V.</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="EmailTo" serializeAs="String">
              <value>webtest@verploegen.nl</value>
          </setting>
    </bdRegisterUserModule.Properties.Settings>
    <bdNavisionLibrary.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="bdNavisionLibrary_AccountService_account" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Account</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVDomain" serializeAs="String">
        <value>VERPLOEGEN</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVUserName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>bluedesk</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="NAVPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Verploegen01</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="bdNavisionLibrary_UserService_User" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/User</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="bdNavisionLibrary_OrderService_Order" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Order</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="bdNavisionLibrary_InvoiceService_Invoice" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Invoice</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="bdNavisionLibrary_ProductService_Product" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://svdh07.verploegen.ads:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Verploegen%20TEST/Codeunit/Product</value>
      </setting>
    </bdNavisionLibrary.Properties.Settings>
    <bdDynamicWebLibrary.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="XsltFile" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://acceptatie.verploegen.bluedesk.nl/files/Templates/bdRegisterUser/CustomerTransform.xslt</value>
      </setting>
    </bdDynamicWebLibrary.Properties.Settings>
    <bdPlaceOrderNotification.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="OrderStatusIdOffer" serializeAs="String">
        <value>OS10</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrderStatusIdNew" serializeAs="String">
        <value>OS1</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="OrderStatusIdBetaling" serializeAs="String">
        <value>OS5</value>
      </setting>
    </bdPlaceOrderNotification.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <!-- when login on root of the site except for these paths /webapi and /admin -->
    <location path="webapi">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="admin">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\Verploegen\AppData\Roaming\Papercut" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

and for example I get on this line:

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

The following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VerploegenTest\application\Web.config    123
```

So it seems there is someting wrong. But is it pure the web.config file. Or is it something else, like mabe the configuration of the project self. I also addes a screenshot how the project looks like.

Thank you.[image]

This is how it looks like in localhost with IIS7 running.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to configure your application in IIS manager? Error states it maybe the cause of the problem if your project in not configured there.

Comment: Yes, it is running in IIS without  any difficults. I can run it in iis

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo

Answer (score 3):

Clean your solution in Release mode.
Clean your solution in Debug mode.
Build your solution in Debug mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I dont see the option clean solution.See my edit post

Comment: Build > Clean Solution

Comment: ?? But I dont see the option clean solution also not in the menu ==> build

Comment: I will attach a screenshot to answer. Try rebuild the solution and see if you then have the option to clean. Otherwise you can just manually delete all the dll's etc which are generated by the build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this occured when changing branch, it created a folder with the name of the branch(I dont know why) and that was the cause of this.

So check if you have 2 web.config in the solution