# Visual Stuio 2017 Asp.Net and IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm using IIS server and visual studio 2017 Asp.net but I keep getting this error. I'm not sure if there's something in IIS that I should configure, I have seen other answers but none solve it.

http://localhost:55167/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Error 1: Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

http://localhost:55167

```
Error: HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo)

Comment: An ASP.NET MVC app should never be accessed in that way. Remove `.cshtml` from URL. Well, get back to a book for beginners please.

Comment: This is a project I'm taking over I'm not use to it like that, that's why i'm looking clarification cause I never use .cshtml before

Comment: Can someone help me with this please.