# User.IsInRole() always returns false only in controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, roleprovider

As in the title `User.IsInRole()` always returns false in controller but works well in view. Additionally I cannot set
`<roleManager enabled="true" />`, because I am getting following error while project building

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Any sugestions? Or is there any other way to check if current user is in role?
(I tried `Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Recruit")` but i got same result). I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and .NET Identity 6.2

Comment: Did you look at the error during build carefully?  Is your application set up in IIS as an application (not a virtual directory)?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo

Comment: Now I discovered that i can use User.IsInRole() in View but cannot use it in a controller. Any ideas?

Comment: *Where* in the controller? Note that the controller constructor runs *before* the user is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Roles.IsUserInRole` is part of MembershipProvider. If you are using Asp.Net Identity, you need to use `RoleManager` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613286(v=vs.108).aspx)) instead.

Reason because you can use `User.IsInRole` - Identity framework supports this call, it looks into a cookie, checks what roles are available in the cookie.