# Error while publishing Asp.net Website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I developed ASP.NET website with SQL Server. And then I try to host in our Company Server machine. I install SQL Server on server machine. And change connection string according to the new server name. After that I deploy my website. After hosting I get this error:

> --Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
> Please review the specific error details below and modify your
> configuration file appropriately.
>
> --Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
> error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
> application in IIS.
>
> Line 22: authentication mode="None"/>

Comment: Have this similar issue post help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo? Try cleaning the project and configure it as application.

Comment: Please refer to the link:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21367324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you have configured the application as a virtual directory in IIS, but not an application.

Right-click on the virtual directory in IIS and select "Convert to Application"