# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, forms-authentication

Hi

I added forms authentication tag in web.config, after that I got this error when I try to start my MVC application in local. Please any help, all other post are about deploying app and this error

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange one - I had the same error - but an easy one to fix.

Simply delete the contents of the obj folder and rebuild.  Ta da!

(I found the answer in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161511/mvc3-strange-error-after-switching-on-compilation-of-views)).

:)

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when there is web project output (templated web.config or temporary publish files) in the obj folder. The ASP.NET compiler used isn't smart enough to ignore stuff in the obj folder, so it throws errors instead.

Another fix is to nuke the publish output right before calling <AspNetCompiler>. Open your .csproj and change this:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

to this:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExtraWebConfigs Include="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\**\web.config" />
    <ExtraPackageTmp Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(&quot;$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)&quot;, &quot;PackageTmp&quot;, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Delete Files="@(ExtraWebConfigs)" />
  <RemoveDir Directories="@(ExtraPackageTmp)" />
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

That will delete all web.configs under \obj, as well as all PackageTmp folders under \obj.